# stack trace typeinfo message

Tags: c++, debugging, rtti, typeinfo

I've had reports of a strange crash that I can't figure out. The code has a simple crash handler to report a stack trace, and this is what the user seeing:

signal 11 (Segmentation fault), address is 0x140d900 from 0x4dcf600
Stack Trace:
[2]: glade : typeinfo for dbObj 259029165 + 259029167

No other stack info. 'dbObj' is a base class of an object widely used in the code, which is compiled with rtti. The crash only seems to occur randomly,so far I cannot reproduce it myself.

Any ideas on how to go about debugging this? It only seems to occur for a particular user, on Linux.

Comment: Can you debug with gdb? If that is you can use commands like where or print dbObj.

Comment: Unfortunately so far I've been unable to reproduce it on a local linux machine.